# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to "Oracle 11g ORDBMS"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have created Object type Inheritance to depict function overriding but it throws an error even though I have written both function definitions correctly and same. Can anyone solve the problem?

1. Create type figures (name ,perimeter() with return value)
2. Create type body Figure as a member function with a return value
3. Create type Triangle (side1,2,3) overriding member function perimeter with return value
4. Create body for Triangle
5. display perimeter value of triangle 6 7 8

**My Solution is**

1.

```
create or replace type figures as object(
  name varchar2(10),
  member function perimeter return number
)not final;
/
```

2.

```
create type body figures as
  member function perimeter return number is
  BEGIN
    return 0;
  END;
END;
/
```

3.

```
create or replace type triangle under figures(
  side1 number,
  side2 number,
  side3 number,
  overriding member function perimeter return number
);
/
```

4.

```
create or replace type body triangle as
  overriding member function perimeter return number is
    total number;
  BEGIN
    total:=self.side1+self.side2+self.side3;
    return total;
  END;
END;
/
```

5.

```
create table tbl_triangle of triangle;

insert into tbl_triangle values('tri',5,6,7);

select triangle.perimeter() from tbl_triangle;    --here the problem occurs
```

Comment: tnx @a_horse_with_no_name plz later teach me how did u formatted code i am new to stack overflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting (or click on the `?` button while editing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is this:

```
SQL> select triangle.perimeter() from tbl_triangle; 
select triangle.perimeter() from tbl_triangle
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PERIMETER'


SQL>
```

This error happens because you are referencing the `triangle` object, so you effectively you are invoking the constructor method.

To get an instance of the object you need to use the `value()` function, which requires a table alias:

```
SQL> select value(t).perimeter() 
  2  from tbl_triangle t
  3  where value(t).name = 'tri'
  4  /

VALUE(T).PERIMETER()
--------------------
                  18

SQL>
```

The `value()` function is described in the documentation. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#i479050).

Comment: You do not need `value(t).name` in the `WHERE` clause; you can just use the column `name` directly.